# Using a specific Lemma, how to prove that between any two distinct rational numbers there exists an irrational number?

Tags: proof-explanation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, number-line

This is probably a really straightforward problem that I'm messing up, but I'm reading a section in a book on irrational numbers and there's a proposition that follows from a lemma, and I'm struggling to see how it follows.

---

**Lemma 2.1:** If *m/n* and *r/s* are rational, with *r/s* $\neq$ 0, then *m/n* + *r/s* $\times$ $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

**Proposition 2.2:** Between any two distinct rational numbers there exists an irrational number.

---

***Proof of Proposition 2.2:***

Let the rational numbers be *m/n* and *r/s*, where *m/n* < *r/s*.

Then, *m/n* $<$   *m/n* + $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (*r/s* - *m/n*) $<$ *r/s*

(because $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} < 1$), and the number in the middle is irrational by the lemma.

---

How is it that you can apply the lemma? Since the lemma refers to the number *m/n* + *r/s* $\times$ $\sqrt{2}$, and the number in the middle is *m/n* + $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (*r/s* - *m/n*). I assume there is some way to manipulate *m/n* + *r/s* $\times$ $\sqrt{2}$ into *m/n* + $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (*r/s* - *m/n*), but I'm struggling to actually do so. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks. Proof is from the book "The Foundations of Mathematics" by Stewart and Tall.

Comment: I guess you can prove that 1) it’s ‘between’ 2) it’s irrational

Comment: Using the same symbol can be confusing at times, but the symbols in the lemma is probably intended to be something else than in the proposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the number $\frac12(r/s-m/n)$ is rational. Call it $r/s$, *at the same time trying to forget that a microsecond ago you used letters $r,s$ to denote something else*. That is how you get that $m/n+\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(r/s-m/n)$ is of the form $m/n+\sqrt 2\times r/s$.

To put it another way: your confusion is that you thought $r,s$ had to mean the same thing in both formulas, but the solution effectively introduces "a new $r$" and "a new $s$".

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

The lemma simply says that if $p$ and $q$ are rational, and $q\ne 0$, then $p+q\sqrt2$ is irrational; it doesn’t matter which rational numbers $p$ and $q$ are (as long as $q\ne 0$). Now take $p=\frac{m}n$ and $q=\frac{r}s-\frac{m}n$; these are rational, and by hypothesis $\frac{m}n<\frac{r}s$, so $q\ne 0$, so the lemma applies to let us conclude that $p+q\sqrt2=\frac{m}n+\sqrt2\left(\frac{r}s-\frac{m}n\right)$ is irrational.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.

Comment: @DavidLoungani: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The general idea would be this:

The rational numbers may be supposed to be positive and written as fractions (not necessarily irreducible) with the same denominator, say $\;\frac ad<\frac bd$.

Now, consider any irrational number $0<\alpha < 1$ (e.g. $\:\alpha =\frac1{\sqrt2}, \frac 1\pi, \frac 1{\mathrm e}$. Then the number
$$c=\frac{\alpha a+(1-\alpha)b}d$$
belongs to the interval $\Bigl[\frac ad,\frac bd\Bigr]$ and is irrational, which is easy to prove by contrapositive:

If for a coefficient $\alpha$, $\:c=\dfrac bd+\alpha\dfrac{a-b}d$ is rational, then $\alpha$ is rational too.

*Note* : One can prove more or less the same way, that between two rational numbers, there exists a transcendental number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna rewrite the lemma without the denominators:

If $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $q\neq 0$ then $p + \sqrt{2}\times q$ is an irrational number.

You want to show that there exists an irrational number between two differents rational numbers $p<q$. The intuitive way to "create" a number between two other numbers given is making their mean: if you call $m=\frac{p+q}{2}$ then you have $p<m<q$

So, following your book, you have $p,q$ and you want to obtain two rationals $a,b$ which verify $p < a + \sqrt{2}\times b < q$. If you need to surpass $p$, the easiest way is taking $a = p$ and adding it something non-negative. So now, you need $b$ making $p + \sqrt{2}\times b < q$, in other words, $b < \frac{q-p}{\sqrt2}$, and you can make this possible if you take $b=\frac{q-p}{2}$, just because $\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, or like you put in parenthesis, because $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} < 1$